# Run munin and all dependencies in userspace on AIX 6.1

Tags: apache-2.2, munin, aix

**Summary:** I would like to have a portable munin in user space without installing anything at all on the client system, (like portable Firefox, without root tasks).

I've downloaded all the dependencies:

```
bash-4.2.tar.gz
gcc-4.7.0.tar.gz
httpd-2.4.2.tar.gz
make-3.82.tar.gz
munin-1.4.7.tar.gz
perl-5.14.2.tar.gz
```

Finally I've installed gcc from an rpm. Also bash from Bull freeware. They are in `/opt/freeware/bin`.

I'm trying to compile httpd and this error appears:

```
bash-4.2$ ./configure
configure: error: cannot find install-sh, install.sh, or shtool in build "."/build
```

I don't want to start installing dependencies, it's going to be endless.

I would like to have munin running in user space to be able to use it on client sites for monitoring and tuning purposes, and after that, delete the folder and leave everything as it was before.

Can someone give me a hint?

Answer (score 0):

You can't build it without the dependencies.  So the hint is, either find someone else who has built it for AIX, or install the dependencies.

Or, and your question isn't clear, if you're trying to run a munin installation somewhere temporarily, use a Linux VM either on your workstation, or depending on your pSeries hardware setup, on the pSeries box.

Just noticed it's httpd (Apache) that you're initially struggling with, why not install an AIX [pre-compiled version of Apache](http://www.perzl.org/aix/index.php?n=Main.Apache)?

Comment: using precompiled binaries. I like it. and I'm going to clarify my question.